How to show weights and coefficient p-values for (multiple) estimation(s) using etable
I'm putting together multiple estimations into one etable() table.
When I do a single estimation using summary() , I get the individual coefficient p-value and the weights used.
Yet when I do a single estimation using etable() , these values are missing. The same for multiple estimations using etable() .
I know how to use fitstat = for many other stats (N, IVF, r2, etc) and coefstat = for tstat or confint.
But don't know how to show p-value and weights.
For example:
When I use:
summary(feols(y ~ 0 | i + t | x ~ z, weights = ~n, df), vcov = "hetero")

I get: Weights: n and Pr(>|t|) for fit_x

TSLS estimation - Dep. Var.: y
                  Endo.    : x
                  Instr.   : z
Second stage: Dep. Var.: y
Observations: 16
Weights: n
Fixed-effects: i: 4,  t: 4
Standard-errors: Heteroskedasticity-robust 
      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
fit_x 0.657899   0.338093 1.94591 0.087543 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
RMSE: 1.42112     Adj. R2: 0.193349
                Within R2: 0.157672
F-test (1st stage), x: stat = 15.1    , p = 0.002542, on 1 and 11 DoF.
           Wu-Hausman: stat =  0.32549, p = 0.586166, on 1 and 7 DoF.

But when I use:
etable(feols(y ~ 0 | i + t | x ~ z, weights = ~n, df), vcov = "hetero")

I don't get the the weights or p-value:
            feols(y ~ 0 | ..
Dependent Var.:                y
                                
x               0.6579. (0.3381)
Fixed-Effects:  ----------------
i                            Yes
t                            Yes
_______________ ________________
S.E. type       Heterosked.-rob.
Observations                  16
R2                       0.56979
Within R2                0.15767

If anyone wants reproducible data:
i <- c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d")
t <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
y <- rnorm(16)
x <- rnorm(16)
z <- rnorm(16)
n <- c(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,6,6,6,6,8,8,8,8)
df <- data.frame(i,t,y,x,z,n)

